# Why use GemSpec + GemFile when checking for dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Whenever developing gems, I don't see any reasons why Gemfile is not directly inspected for dependencies.

Indeed, why use a `.gemspec` file in order to list them ? Is there a real benefit ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well that's because the `Gemfile` isn't a file from Rubygems, but a file from Bundler. So the Rubygem developers would have to extend their used files in order to support Gemfile. Since there already is the `.gemspec` file, there is no valid reason why they should. (there are enough gems which do well without a `Gemfile`)

In fact, [it is recommended](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) to use this as the only contents of the `Gemfile` of gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```

It will instruct bundler to use the `.gemspec` file as the authorative source of gems.